# Poetry pytest, ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fastapi'

Tags: python, pytest, fastapi, python-poetry

I'm running `FastAPI` successfully with Poetry but I cannot run unit tests:

```
poetry run pytest
platform linux -- Python 3.11.5, pytest-7.4.1, pluggy-1.3.0
rootdir: /home/jenia/git/example00
collected 0 items / 1 error                                                                                                                                                                  

app/example.py:2: in <module>
    from fastapi import FastAPI
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fastapi'
```

I executed the poetry shell:

```
[jenia@archlinux example00]$ poetry shell
Spawning shell within /home/jenia/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/example00-IayGs80J-py3.11
[jenia@archlinux example00]$ . /home/jenia/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/example00-IayGs80J-py3.11/bin/activate
(example00-py3.11) [jenia@archlinux example00]$
```

Still the error persists.

Here is my file that I need to test `app/example.py`:

```
import socket
from fastapi import FastAPI #<======== I know it's unused, it's for demonstration/learning purposes.

def resolvePostgres():
    x = socket.getaddrinfo('postgres', 5432)
```

And here is the test `tests/test_example.py`:

```
import unittest
from unittest import mock
from app.example import resolvePostgres


class TestStringMethods(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_example(self):
        resolvePostgres()
```

However I can run the program no problem with `uvicorn main:app`:

```
which uvicorn
/home/jenia/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/example00-IayGs80J-py3.11/bin/uvicorn
```

Here is the file structure:

```
|--example00/
   |--app/
      |--__init__.py
      |--example.py
   |--tests/
      |--__init__.py
      |--test_example.py
   |--main.py
   |--pyproject.toml
```

And finally, here is my `pyproject.toml`:

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "example00"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["Evgeniy"]
readme = "README.md"
packages = [{include = "app"}]

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.11"
fastapi = "^0.100.1"
uvicorn = {extras = ["standard"], version = "^0.23.2"}
app = "^0.0.1"


[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

Can someone please give me a hint, how do I run the tests in such a way that the import get resolved properly?

Comment: I had to do `poetry add -D pytest` and I worked. I'm not 100% understanding. I need to a little more how poetry works

Comment: You may be having `pytest` installed globally, so even if you call it inside env shell it still uses global python executable and does not see any package inside that environment